# *RxJs* How to combine multiple ajax to one observable that doesn't require sequence

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

[image]

I have two API to get menu data on Angular5, but I don't know if I use nested subscribe that getSecondMenu function is the correct way of RxJs. Does anyone have any idea, below is expected result and sample code:

`console.log:
1. get firstMenuList
2. all done
3. get secondMenu * 3`

[open on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8dn3ggp/16/)

```js
getFirstMenu$()
  .do(firstMenuList => {
    console.log('get firstMenuList');
  })
  .do(firstMenuList => {
    firstMenuList.forEach(firstMenu => {
      // nested subscribe : bind to child property, let Angular auto-generate second Menu in HTML
      getSecondMenu$(firstMenu.ID).subscribe((secondMenu) => {
        firstMenu.child = secondMenu;
        console.log('get secondMenu');
      });
    })
  })
  .subscribe((menuList) => {
    console.log('all done' );
  });


function getFirstMenu$() {
  return Rx.Observable.of([{
    ID: 'menu1',
    child: null
  }, {
    ID: 'menu2',
    child: null
  }, {
    ID: 'menu3',
    child: null
  }, ]);
}

function getSecondMenu$(menuID) {
  let source = null;
  switch (menuID) {
    case 'menu1':
      source = [{
        ID: 'subMenu1-1',
      }];
      break;
    case 'menu2':
      source = [{
        ID: 'subMenu2-1',
      }];
      break;
    default:
      source = [];
      break;
  }
  const delayTime = ((Math.random() * 20) + 5) * 120;
  return Rx.Observable.of(source).delay(delayTime);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.8/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

---

## Conclusion

thanks, @Fan Cheung talk a lot about how to combine multiple observable, to summarize you have two way to do that

[image]

### use callback

```js
// componnet
class myComponent {
  getMenu() {
    new sharedService().getMenu({
      getFirstMenuList: () => {
        console.log('render first menu to template...')
      }
    })
  }
}

// shared service
class sharedService {
  getMenu(callback) {
    this.getFirstMenu$()
      .mergeMap(firstMenuList => {
        console.log('get first menu');
        //
        if (callback.getFirstMenuList) {
          callback.getFirstMenuList(firstMenuList);
        }

        return Rx.Observable.from(firstMenuList);
      })
      .mergeMap(firstMenu => this.getSecondMenu$(firstMenu.ID), (firstMenu, secondMenu) => {
        //
        console.log('get second menu');
        //
        firstMenu.child = secondMenu
        return firstMenu;
      })
      .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])
      .subscribe((menuList) => {
        console.log('all done');
      });
  }

  getFirstMenu$() {
    return Rx.Observable.of([{
      ID: 'menu1',
      child: null
    }, {
      ID: 'menu2',
      child: null
    }, {
      ID: 'menu3',
      child: null
    }, ]);
  }

  getSecondMenu$(menuID) {
    let source = null;
    switch (menuID) {
      case 'menu1':
        source = [{
          ID: 'subMenu1-1',
        }];
        break;
      case 'menu2':
        source = [{
          ID: 'subMenu2-1',
        }];
        break;
      default:
        source = [];
        break;
    }
    const delayTime = ((Math.random() * 20) + 5) * 120;
    return Rx.Observable.of(source).delay(delayTime);
  }
}

// getTemplate
new myComponent().getMenu();
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.8/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

### return other function to subscribe

```js
// componnet
class myComponent {
  getMenu() {
    new sharedService().getMenu().subscribe(() => {
        console.log('render first menu to template...');      
    })
  }
}

// shared service
class sharedService {
  getMenu() {
    return this.getFirstMenu$()
      .mergeMap(firstMenuList => {
        console.log('get first menu');
        return Rx.Observable.from(firstMenuList);
      })
      .mergeMap(firstMenu => this.getSecondMenu$(firstMenu.ID), (firstMenu, secondMenu) => {
        //
        console.log('get second menu');
        //
        firstMenu.child = secondMenu
        return firstMenu;
      })
      .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])
      .do((menuList) => {
        console.log('all done');
      });
  }

  getFirstMenu$() {
    return Rx.Observable.of([{
      ID: 'menu1',
      child: null
    }, {
      ID: 'menu2',
      child: null
    }, {
      ID: 'menu3',
      child: null
    }, ]);
  }

  getSecondMenu$(menuID) {
    let source = null;
    switch (menuID) {
      case 'menu1':
        source = [{
          ID: 'subMenu1-1',
        }];
        break;
      case 'menu2':
        source = [{
          ID: 'subMenu2-1',
        }];
        break;
      default:
        source = [];
        break;
    }
    const delayTime = ((Math.random() * 20) + 5) * 120;
    return Rx.Observable.of(source).delay(delayTime);
  }
}

// getTemplate
new myComponent().getMenu();
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.8/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: ForEach .subscribe looks like a sure way to get memory leaks.. even without nested second call

Comment: @c69 what good way can I avoid memory leaks? use flatMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
getFirstMenu$()
.map(firstMenuList => Observable.from(firstMenuList))
.flatMap(firstMenu=> getSecondMenu$(firstMenu.ID))
.do(secondMenu => firstMenu.child = secondMenu)
.subcribe()
```

edit1

```
getFirstMenu$()
.mergeMap(firstMenuList => Rx.Observable.from(firstMenuList))
.mergeMap(firstMenu=> getSecondMenu$(firstMenu.ID)
,(firstMenu, secondMenu) => {
 firstMenu.child=secondMenu
 return firstMenu
 })
.reduce((acc,curr)=>  acc.concat(curr) ,[])
.subscribe((menuList) => {
 console.log(menuList)
 });
```

Comment: in this sample I don't know how should I get menuList data, I try it on this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkj1f3k9/), would you help me to correct it?

Comment: you can mock one like getFirstMenu$=()=>Observable.of([{lable:'one'},{lable:'two'}]) and use it in fiddle

Comment: I had used Observable.of in jsFiddle, you can check it on this link https://jsfiddle.net/jkj1f3k9/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fancheung/rjL8dwyv/ 
forked and updated your fiddle

Comment: thanks your answer, I added a timeline to the expected result, hope it let my question to be simple, would you check this [image](https://sketch.io/render/sk-bdf954491b719317c446d414a0f2d72a.jpeg) and this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fancheung/rjL8dwyv/)

Comment: so you want to do some operation before fetching second menu? you can easily insert it in second mergemap method. In good reactive programming we don't nest subscribe

Comment: In fact, I have a more component to call a shared service(open this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs4Rl.png)), does it mean that I need to add a callback to function? like this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frpveL6a/)

Comment: or have some operation of RxJS can ignore the callback?

Comment: you dont have to use callback with observable. just return it for other function to subscribe() https://jsfiddle.net/fancheung/frpveL6a/3/

Comment: thanks, I got the same problem that the sequence is not my expected when I try to subscribe return function, you can check this [image](https://sketch.io/render/sk-0e373eb9c456cf56345dad24d7e2ddce.jpeg)  and below jsfiddle, [callback](https://jsfiddle.net/frpveL6a/) 、 [other function to subscribe](https://jsfiddle.net/ttqbc2g3/)

Comment: but the sequence is wrong of my second example , https://sketch.io/render/sk-0e373eb9c456cf56345dad24d7e2ddce.jpeg

Comment: The sequence is correct for your requirement. Code in subscribe always run last. If you want to do things in between you can always use map, do operator in between. If you want the first menu to render immediately after you fetch the data just assign it to a template variable. like this.firstMenu=firstMenu